# Nested while loop needed?

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-views

I've got this code working but it's only pulling out the first neighbourhood group that matches one of the values from the 1st query. The code is in a Node ID PHP handler in a view in Drupal.

The first query puts all of the postal codes from the government's jurisdiction into an array.  The second query reads through all of the neighbourhood groups to find all those that match those in that array.

It looks like I need a second loop or something since the while that's there now isn't getting every neighbourhood groups that match any of the values in the array.  Can anyone see what I'm missing?

### Here's the code:

```
$government_nid = custom_get_groupid();

$codes_list = array();
$neighbourhood_list = array();

$results = db_query("SELECT field_jurisdiction_postal_codes_value FROM   {content_field_jurisdiction_postal_codes}  WHERE
nid = %d", $government_nid);
while($return_list = db_fetch_array($results)){
$codes_list[] = $return_list[field_jurisdiction_postal_codes_value];
}


$results1 = db_query("SELECT  nid FROM  {content_type_neighbourhood_group}  WHERE
field_postal_code_3_value IN ('%s')", $codes_list);
while($return_list1 = db_fetch_array($results1)){
$neighbourhood_list[] = $return_list1[nid];
}
$neighbourhood_string = implode(', ', $neighbourhood_list);

return $neighbourhood_string;
```

Comment: Here's the answer: 
foreach ($codes_list AS $value)  {
$results1 = db_query("SELECT  nid FROM  {content_type_neighbourhood_group}  WHERE
field_postal_code_3_value = '%s'", $value);
while($return_list1 = db_fetch_array($results1)){
$neighbourhood_list[] = $return_list1[nid];
}
}
$neighbourhood_string = implode(', ', $neighbourhood_list);

return $neighbourhood_string;

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

```
foreach ($codes_list AS $value)  {
$results1 = db_query("SELECT  nid FROM  {content_type_neighbourhood_group}  WHERE
field_postal_code_3_value = '%s'", $value);
while($return_list1 = db_fetch_array($results1)){
$neighbourhood_list[] = $return_list1[nid];
}
}
$neighbourhood_string = implode(', ', $neighbourhood_list);

return $neighbourhood_string;
```